# Getting Segmentation Fault error in C++ code

Tags: c++, error-handling, segmentation-fault

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//FIRST REPEATING ELEMENT (APPROACH 2)

int main()
{
    cout<<"running";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    const int N = 1e5+2;
    int idx[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        idx[i] = -1;

    int minidx = INT_MAX;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(idx[arr[i]] != -1)
            minidx = min(minidx, idx[arr[i]]);
        else
            idx[arr[i]] = i;
    }

    if(minidx == INT_MAX)
        cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<minidx + 1<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I am writing this code for "First Repeating Element" question and trying to get the index of the first element that repeats.
On debugging, I am getting segmentation fault.
int main()
{ (in this line)

What does it mean and what can I do to remove this.

Comment: Better to avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h.

Comment: Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int N = 1e5+2;
int idx[N];
```

That sounds like a big array to be allocated on the stack (400kb!). Try using malloc() to allocate an array of that size. Change that to something like

```
const int N = 1e5+2;
int* idx = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

You should also do the same for `arr`, particularly if you use large values for n.

Answer (score 1):

The program has **undefined behavior** because you're going out of bound of the array. This is because in your `for` loop condition, you're using `i<=n` instead of `i<n`.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

Additionally, in Standard C++ the size of an array must be a compile time constant. This means that the following is incorrect in your program.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n]; //not standard C++ since n is not a constant expression
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is due to usage of memory that you don't own, or in other words stack over flow. Most likely because you're creating an array of size 1e5+2 and looping over it, initializing every element.  That's not the best way to find the recurrence of an element.  Instead use a map with key value pairs.

Comment: "Segmentation fault is due to over using memory" that's not appropriate. A segmentation fault typically means that you are using memory you don't own. The stack overflow case here is the exception.